# Python - Bit variable's size is always 24, instead of its size

Tags: python, python-2.7

If `0b0` represents the 1-bit "0", why does `sys.getsizeof(0b0)` yield 24? Furthermore, `sys.getsizeof` always yield 24, not matter how long is the size of the binary value you give it.

Shouldn't `sys.getsizeof(0b0)` yield 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python cannot store a 1-bit value in 1 bit of memory, or even 1 byte. There's overhead like the type pointer and the reference count, and its `int` type always uses a fixed number of bytes to store the actual number it represents, either 4 or 8 bytes depending on your Python build. (There's also the `long` type, which isn't fixed-size, but even that type uses chunks bigger than one byte.)

Comment: Thanks, i get it now. However, now I have a follow up question. Could a binary variable be stored in a file, in order to create a file that has a 1-bit content?

Comment: @user3264316 no, since now you're dealing with file management which will of course never chunk sectors into 1 bit segments.

Answer (score 1):

user2357112 does a great job of describing what `sys.getsizeof` gives you. If, instead, you're trying to ask "How do I get the number of significant digits in a number," you could try:

```
len(bin(some_num)) - 2 # strips 0b
```

Or, and thanks for user2357112's comment:

```
max(some_num.bit_length(), 1)  # minimum bound since (0).bit_length() == 0
```

Comment: Or `some_num.bit_length()`, though it has the difference that `0 .bit_length() == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Like user2357112 said, those 24 bytes mostly include management data. And it *does* get larger than 24, you just haven't tried a large enough number yet:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(0b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)
42
```

If you want to ask "how many bits a number has", use the `bit_length` method:

```
>>> 0b0.bit_length()
0
>>> 0b1.bit_length()
1
>>> 0b1010101.bit_length()
7
```

Answer (score 1):

`0b0` does not represent the *1-bit* 0, but the *integer* zero. The `0b` prefix is just a way to write numbers in the base-2 instead of the base-10 system.

To get the number of bits necessary to represent an integer, use the [`bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method.